# Ascending Order Error for Selected Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my table I'm trying select from the BusinessEntityID column and order it by ascending order starting from the lowest 38 ... to the highest 2357. When I execute this query, I don't get the results I'm looking for I get the first the first top ten rows instead.

**Without Order By**

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014] --Database Name

Select top 10 [FirstName], [LastName], [BusinessEntityID]

From [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
```

**Results:**

```
FirstName                      LastName                            BusinessEntityID
------------------------------ ----------------------------------- ----------------
Syed                           Abbas                               285
Catherine                      Abel                                293
Kim                            Abercrombie                         295
Kim                            Abercrombie                         2170
Kim                            Abercrombie                         38
Hazem                          Abolrous                            211
Sam                            Abolrous                            2357
Humberto                       Acevedo                             297
Gustavo                        Achong                              291
Pilar                          Ackerman                            299
```

**Order by Ascending Order**

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014] --Database Name

Select top 10 [FirstName], [LastName], [BusinessEntityID]

From [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]

Order By [BusinessEntityID] ASC
```

**Results:**

```
FirstName            LastName            BusinessEntityID
-------------------- ------------------- ----------------
Ken                  Sánchez             1
Terri                Duffy               2
Roberto              Tamburello          3
Rob                  Walters             4
Gail                 Erickson            5
Jossef               Goldberg            6
Dylan                Miller              7
Diane                Margheim            8
Gigi                 Matthew             9
Michael              Raheem              10
```

Comment: First query is meaning less. `Top` with `Order by` will produce arbitrary results. From second query, I can say Lowest `BusinessEntityID` is `1` and not `38` even second query works as expected.

Comment: If you want to filter the `BusinessEntityID's` from  `38` to `2357` then use `Where` clause and `Order by BusinessEntityID`. Remove `TOP` keyword

Comment: I see, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you want the first 10 lastnames, so you can do it this way:

```
select * from (
    Select top 10 [FirstName], [LastName], [BusinessEntityID]
    From [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
    order by LastName, FirstName
) X
order by BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. I will mark as answered.

Comment: @taji01 I now see what OP was going for.  +1 for the correct interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `TOP 10` and add a `WHERE`

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014] --Database Name
Select [FirstName], [LastName], [BusinessEntityID]
From [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
Where [BusinessEntityID] between 38 and 2357
Order By [BusinessEntityID] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this one too

USE [AdventureWorks2014] --Database Name

Select top 10 [FirstName], [LastName], [BusinessEntityID]

From [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person] WHERE [BusinessEntityID] >= 38 AND [BusinessEntityID] <= 2357

Order By [BusinessEntityID] ASC